# Android Volley and making two requests parallel to pass data to next activity

Tags: android, asynchronous, async-await, android-volley

I'm new to Android development and hence the following question is:
I need to make two REST request to get data from two different sources and then pass to my next Activity. How can I do that?

```
ArrayList<T> data1 = GetDataFromSource1();
 ArrayList<T> data2 = GetDataFromSource2();
```

Is there any concept of async-wait like in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the volley library usage example :

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/humans.txt";

RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, future, future)
mRequestQueue.add(request);

String result = future.get(); // this line will block
```

To Set parameters you can do the following

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,
  new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
      Log.e("HttpClient", "success! response: " + response.toString());
    }
  },
  new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
      Log.e("HttpClient", "error: " + error.toString());
    }
  })
  {
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
      Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
      params.put("user","YOUR USERNAME");
      params.put("pass","YOUR PASSWORD");
      return params;
    }
  };
```

documentaion can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request)

Comment: If you override onResponse or onErrorResponse ect... they are called on UI thread so any heavy operation done inside these methods will make you application slower! so short answer no

Comment: Thanks again for the response. I don't need to do heavy stuff on Response apart from converting the json to my objects.
Could you please show some code how can I pass the headers and parameters to this request and also how can convert back the json using Gson.

Comment: I just edited the answer to put more details about param took the example of user and pass, same with headers you need to override the method getHeaders() feel free to let me know if you are stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer how you can pass your ArrayList between Activities.
You can implement Parcelable into your object class.

```
public class Currency implements Parcelable {

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Currency> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Currency>() {
    public Currency createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Currency(in);
    }

    public Currency[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Currency[size];
    }
};

...
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

//Order must be the same as read
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeLong(code);
    out.writeString(name);
    out.writeString(swiftSymbol);
    out.writeString(symbol);
}

//Order must be the same as write
private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    code = in.readLong();
    name = in.readString();
    swiftSymbol = in.readString();
    symbol = in.readString();
}
```

And then you can pass it like this;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this,TargetActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(tagOne,data1);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(tagTwo,data2);
startActivity(intent);
```